# Get value from within a <span> and apply a styleclass with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code which will take the value from within a  and apply some css properties if it is greater than 60.

```
$(".over").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var value = parseFloat(el.text());
    if (value > 60) {
        el
            .css("font-weight", "bold")
            .css("color", "red");

    } else {

        el.css("font-weight", "bold");
    }
});

<body>
<span class="over">60</span>
<span class="over">61</span>
</body>
```

However I need to add some text also within this  so I need to adapt the code to find the value within the string and if that is greater than 60 apply the css.
For example:

```
<body>
<span class="over">This number is 60</span>
<span class="over">This number is 61</span>
</body>
```

I can't figure out how to write it correctly. I have copied most of the code from someone else.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a regular expression to find the numerical value within the text of the element:

```js
$(".over").each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var value = parseFloat($el.text().match(/\d+/)[0]);
  if (value > 60) {
    $el.css({
      "font-weight": "bold",
      "color": "red"
    });
  } else {
    $el.css("font-weight", "bold");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="over">This number is 60</span>
<span class="over">This number is 61</span>
<span class="over">62 is the number</span>
```

You should note though that setting CSS properties in JS code is generally considered bad practice and should be avoided. To fix this you can use classes to apply the styles and use the JS code to change the classes as needed. Try this:

```js
$(".over").each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var value = parseFloat($el.text().match(/\d+/)[0]);
  $el.toggleClass('foo', value > 60);
});
```

```css
.over {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.over.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="over">This number is 60</span>
<span class="over">This number is 61</span>
<span class="over">62 is the number</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a regex to get the number from the text like `el.text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')`

```js
$(".over").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var value = parseFloat(el.text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    console.log(value);
    if (value > 60) {
        el
            .css("font-weight", "bold")
            .css("color", "red");

    } else {

        el.css("font-weight", "bold");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<span class="over">This number is 60</span>
<span class="over">This number is 61</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

**Sample Code**

```js
$(".over").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var val = el.text();
    var re = /\s*\s/;
    var lines = val.split(re); // it will return array with 4 element. 
    var value = parseFloat(el.text());
     if (lines[3] > 60) {       // here i'm using directly 4th no element
        el
            .css("font-weight", "bold")
            .css("color", "red");

      } else {

        el.css("font-weight", "bold");
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<span class="over">This number is 60</span>
<span class="over">This number is 61</span>
</body>
```